# List index out of range using csv module

Tags: python, list, csv, indexing, range

I'm using this information (downloaded the file to my computer) http://www.genome.gov/admin/gwascatalog.txt

and wrote this

```
import csv

path = '/Users/mtchavez/Documents/ALS/Diseasome/GWAS.txt'
read_file = open(path)
reader = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter = '\t')
fieldnames = reader.next()

rows = list(reader)
read_file.close()

write_file = open('datatest.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(write_file, delimiter = '\t')
writer.writerow(('disease', 'genes'))

disease_gene = dict()
for row in rows:
    disease = row[7]
    reported_genes = row[13]
```

but I get an error message:

```
     File "data1.py", line 18, in <module>
    disease = row[7]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What do you get if you `print(row)`?

Answer (score 0):

There is an empty line at the end of this csv file and it will create an empty row.  Delete the last line and the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering for empty lines:

```
for row in rows:
    if not row: continue
    disease = row[7]
    reported_genes = row[13]
```

Or more specifically, filter for the desired length:

```
for row in rows:
    if len(row) != EXPECTED_LENGTH_OF_RECORD: continue
    disease = row[7]
    reported_genes = row[13]
```